# EntityValue timeline

Tags: syntax, finance, entity

I try to use `EntityValue` to get the returns of a stock from January 1st 2019 to today. When I use

```
EntityValue[Entity["Financial", StringJoin["NYSE:", "BMY"]], "Return"]
```

I obtain the latest return.

What syntax should I use for the third argument in `EntityValue` to get a time period?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`EntityProperty`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EntityProperty) to add a qualifier:

```
ts = EntityValue[
    Entity["Financial",StringJoin["NYSE:","BMY"]],
    EntityProperty["Financial","Return",{"Date"->{DateObject@{2019,1,1}, Today}}]
]
```

> [image]

You can extract the data using "DatePath":

```
ts["DatePath"] //Short[#, 5]&
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to obtain the actual data and not an interpolation?

Comment: @NeutralElement See update.

Answer (score 2):

Using `Interpreter` and appropriate ids from [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CompanyData.html),  we can make it more general. Here is a short function.

```
plotCompanyFundamentalData[symbol_, startDate_, endDate_, ids_] := 
 Module[{mycompany, mycompanydata},
mycompany = EntityValue[Interpreter["Company"][symbol], "Company"];
  mycompanydata =EntityValue[mycompany,Dated[ids, 
Interval[{DateObject[startDate], DateObject[endDate]}]]];
DateListPlot[mycompanydata, PlotLabel -> symbol, PlotLegends -> ids, 
PlotTheme -> "Detailed", PlotRange -> All]]
```

Example:

```
 plotCompanyFundamentalData["AAPL", {2000, 1, 1}, {2019, 1, 1},
 {"ROA","ROE","RevenueGrowth"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `FinancialData` instead:

```
FinancialData[
  StringJoin["NYSE:", "BMY"], 
  "Return", 
  {DateObject[{2019, 1, 1}], Today}
]

{{{2019, 3, 4}, -0.00319433}, {{2019, 3, 5}, 0.0141376}, {{2019, 3, 6}, -0.0169145}, 
 {{2019, 3, 7}, -0.0283607}, {{2019, 3, 11}, -0.00953489}, {{2019, 3, 12}, -0.0102161}, 
 {{2019, 3, 13}, 0.011711}, {{2019, 3, 14}, -0.021189}, {{2019, 3, 15}, 0.00140308}, 
 {{2019, 3, 18}, -0.00200157}, {{2019, 3, 19}, -0.00521464}, {{2019, 3, 20}, -0.00826613}, 
 {{2019, 3, 21}, -0.00548893}}
```

Comment: I try to avoid FinancialData because sometimes is unavailable and is extremely slow. Your previous command did not work for me.